# REGEXP Function Help - Looker Studio (Google Data Studio)

Tags: sql, regex, function, split, looker

I hope everyone is doing well!

I am trying to extract/clean data from a column. Below is an example of a cell row:

"Mother Day Pack - 200ml / 10 Cans 1 glass & 1 crisp"

What I need to do is to

Separate the text data before the hyphen (-) and extract only "Mother Day Pack"

Separate the numeric data between the hypen (-) and the slash (/) and extract only "200"

Separate the first 2-digit numeric data after the slash (/) and extract only "10"

My thoughts are to duplicate the same columns x3 then use a REGEXP_EXTRACT or REPLACE (). However, I never used it before, so I would really appreciate your help to build the 3 queries

Thanks

I tried this REGEXP_EXTRACT(product_name,'.*?/') but it only captured the 200 so I am looking for the rest. Thanks

Comment: You can use the following pattern, _(.+) - (\d+).+\/ (\d+)_

Answer (score 0):

Do this assuming your target text `Mother Day Pack - 200ml / 10 Cans 1 glass & 1 crisp` is in A1:

- `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.*?) -")` -- returns: `Mother Day Pack`

  - explanation: scan and capture non-greedily everything up to  `-`
- `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, " -[^\d](\d+)")` -- returns `200`

  - explanation: scan over the first `-` and anything that is not a digit, and capture all digits after that
- `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, " /[^\d](\d+)")` -- returns `10`

  - explanation: scan over the first `/` and anything that is not a digit, and capture all digits after that

This is Google Spreadsheet specific.

**Edit 2023-06-23**

Here is the Google Data Studio specific example:

- `REGEXEXTRACT(DIMENSION, '(.*?) -')` -- returns: `Mother Day Pack`
- `REGEXEXTRACT(DIMENSION, '-[^\\d](\\d+)')` -- returns `200`
  and capture all digits after that
- `REGEXEXTRACT(DIMENSION, ' /[^\\d](\\d+)')` -- returns `10`

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Comment: Hello @peter, thank you very much! The 3 formulas worked. I slighlty adjusted them to work on Looker's (GDS) formatting. If anyone is interested in this, these are the codes I used: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(DIMENSION, '(.*?) -')` , `REGEXP_EXTRACT(DIMENSION, '-[^\\d](\\d+)')` , `REGEXP_EXTRACT(DIMENSION,' /[^\\d](\\d+)')`                     Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Jayx. I updated the answer accordingly.